# How to categorize income in Excel?

Tags: excel, currency

I have a column in Excel that holds data in Euros, then another column for description and **third column for category.**
I want to count all EUROS for each Category. How much was spend for each category.

Please check my image:
[image]

Comment: Unless you intend to solve that with VBA or .NET, I suggest asking in a sister site of Stack Overflow, [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know the sum for a particular category, you can use the SUMIF function (`=SUMIF(D:D,"...",C:C)`)

If you want to know the sums for each category, you can use a pivot table that summarizes with sum

Comment: That syntax (with SUM range first) is for SUMIFS. SUMIF has sum range last, i.e. here for a category listed in F3, `=SUMIF(E:E,F3,C:C)`

Comment: I recommend the pivot table approach.